# Verificar a cor predominante na imagem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, imagem

Eu tenho o seguinte código que irei colocar abaixo, que é responsável por pegar a imagem da qual o usuário coloca. Nesse caso, a variável `img` me retorna somente a url da imagem. Eu queria pegar a imagem e ver qual é a cor que predomina na mesma.

Segue o **código:**

```
<input type="file" accept='image/*' name="imagem" id="img">
<button id="carregar" onclick="carrega()">Carregar</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function carrega() {
    var img = $('#img').val();
    alert(img);
    console.log('Img: '+img);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Com a URL da imagem, você pode mandar uma requisição GET pra obter a imagem em si e aí fazer o processamento que quiser nela.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embora não seja possível demonstrar o funcionamento aqui no snippet, você consegue identificar a cor predominante de uma imagem utilizando a biblioteca [Color Thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/). É importante de que a imagem a ser verificada esteja renderizada na página, mas se não quiser mostrá-la, basta utilizar um `display:none` no css.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Carrega a imagem selecionada na <img id="imagem">
  function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#imagem').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }

  $("#inputImg").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
  });

  //Captura a cor predominante do elemento <img id="imagem">
  $("#capturar").on('click', function() {  
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var sourceImage = document.getElementById("imagem");
    var color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
    console.clear();
    console.log(color);
    $("#cor").css('background-color', "rgb(" + color + ")");
  });
});
```

```css
#imagem {
  display: none;
}

#cor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/js/color-thief.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="file" accept='image/*' id="inputImg">
  <br>
  <img id="imagem" src="" width="50%" style="" />
  <br>
  <button id="capturar">Capturar</button>
  <div id="cor"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado por toda a ajuda!